# What is the maximum MS Reporting Services Instances allowed?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, multiple-instances, ssrs-2012

Let me explain my problem:
I'm using an Amazon EC2 instance as a DB and Report Server, currently the server has 11 Reporting Services instances installed and around 40 databases (22 from Reporting instances).

We started having [performance issues](http://screencast.com/t/wRNAyH1TykV) and some Reporting Services were stopped by the system because the server did not have enough memory. We upgraded the EC2 instance and we now have 30GB of memory on the server, this fixed the memory issues.

Now that we upgraded the DB server we are planning to install more Reporting Services instances, I searched in the MS documentation but I could not find if there is a limit of Reporting Services instances that we can install on one server.  Also, even though the requirements says 1GB of memory per SSRS installation I think that the current installations are using [around 300MB](http://screencast.com/t/t8rkQ4iUhTmm)

I want to clarify that we are installing separate instances because the reports deployed and configuration are different so we can't use the "Scale-Out Deployment" model where several Reporting Services point to a single database. That means that for each SSRS instance that we add we also deploy the two SSRS databases (Reports and TempDB) on the same server.

Does anybody knows if there is a limit of SSRS instances installed on the same server or as long as we add memory and CPU we should be fine installing all these SSRS instances in the same box?

Is there a point (i.e. 20 SSRS instances) at which we should fire up a new server and install the instances in a separate server?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2014 maximum instances per node is [50 for standalone and 25 for failover clustered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms143432.aspx). Never tried, but most surely the limit will be the same por Reporting Services, as SSRS are installed as a SQL Server instance feature subset.

Now for the capacity requirements, from my experience I would not never provision less than 1vCPU and 2GB RAM per SSRS instance, but that will depend on your application requirements, no magic numbers :-(